# Editor field outputs Site Page links as {page_xxx} variable

Tags: devdemon, editor

When using the link dialog to add a link to a Site Page, the URL looks correct in the Editor, but when the page is rendered, it just spits out {page_xxx} and not the URL. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Site is running EE 2.11.3 and Editor 3.2.4

Comment: I'm an idiot. I'm seeing this problem because I'm rendering the field content inside a Category Sorted Entries tag. that add-on can't handle complex custom field data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this problem because I'm rendering the field content inside a [Category Sorted Entries](https://rog.ee/category_sorted_entries/) tag. That add-on can't handle complex custom field data.